# Issue : "No content to map to Object due to end of input" in test classes

Tags: integration, code-coverage, apextestrunresult

I am getting Issue in test class. I am not able to cover the test coverage of responsebody
When I debug it show the "common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: No content to map to Object due to end of input"

[image]

Kindly help me

**Mockresponse generator**

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
global String respond(HTTPRequest req) {
if(req.getEndpoint() == 'https://sandbox- 
 quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/4620816365*******/customer?minorversion=65'){
 HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 res.setBody('{"Customer":{"Taxable":true,"Job":false,"BillWithParent":false,"Balance":0,"BalanceWithJobs":0,"CurrencyRef":{"value":"USD","name":"United States Dollar"},"PreferredDeliveryMethod":"Print","IsProject":false,"domain":"QBO","sparse":false,"Id":"277","SyncToken":"0","MetaData":{"CreateTime":"2023-04-04T06:21:47-07:00","LastUpdatedTime":"2023-04-04T06:21:47-07:00"},"GivenName":"Mohit","FamilyName":"Sharma","FullyQualifiedName":"Test Mohit","CompanyName":"Test Mohit","DisplayName":"Test Mohit","PrintOnCheckName":"Test Mohit","Active":true,"PrimaryPhone":{"FreeFormNumber":"87983423049"},"WebAddr":{"URI":"https://www.google.com"},"DefaultTaxCodeRef":{"value":"2"}},"time":"2023-04-04T06:21:47.112-07:00"}');
 res.setStatusCode(200); 
 return res;
}
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
return res;
 }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
public static void testMethod1(){
    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.Class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
      QbPostandGetCls.Create_Customer();
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

In the main class QbPostandGetCls method Create_Customer returntype is map<String,String>

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: hard-coding sandbox endpoints in your mock is not a good idea - the test needs to run in all environments, including PROD

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you mock is not matching the endpoint? Thus responding with an empty httpresponse

what i mean is :

```
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
     global String respond(HTTPRequest req) {
         if(req.getEndpoint() == 'ENDPOINT'){ //----> HERE NO MATCH
             HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
             res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
             res.setBody('your JSON');
             res.setStatusCode(200); 
             return res;
         }
         HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(); //----> thus creating this
         return res; //----> and there is nothing in there (no 200 or whatever)
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Philippe for your help. Yes the mock is not matching the endpoint